# How to get this number format in java?

Tags: java

Lets say I am having a number as follows :

```
long number = 32301672060;
```

I want the following the format for the number :

> 323.016.720,60

i.e the last two digits should be separated by comma and then dot between every three digits.

Suppose the another number is :

```
long number = 139454
```

then output should be

> 1.394,54

Comment: do you need a code, or you want if any API exists that you can use to get that format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    long number = 32301672060L;

    NumberFormat nb = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    nb.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    System.out.println(nb.format((double)number/100));
```

This should work for you. The German Local is important to have the point as decimal point and the comma at the last 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the value to a `double`, divide it by 100 (to get the 2 decimal points) and then set the current locale to something like `de_DE` and use [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to format it for you.

Edit: As noted by Behrang in the comments, after converting the long to a double, it should only be used for display purposes as further calculations using this might result in loss of precision.

Comment: Don't do this. You might lose precision.

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh, `format(...)` or `printf(...)` is only used for display purposes, ho1 isn't suggesting to convert the number itself.

Comment: @Bart: He says `Cast the value to a double, divide it by 100`. This way you can lose precision.

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh, could you show me a `long` that, after casting to a `double`, does not equal this `double` value?

Comment: @Bart: There are longs, that "after being cast to double **AND** divided by 100" and then multiplied by 100 and converted to long, won't return the same value.

Comment: @Behrang: As Bart said though, I only meant this answer for display purposes. However, I'll amend the answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Behrang, that's not what I meant (or said). What I did say before is that no-one suggested multiplying the number with 100 to get the original value back. My point is that the casting to double (and division with 100) is safe in such a way that for any `long X = abcdefghij` the output will always be the string: `"ab.cde.fgh,ij"`. I.e., the "precision" `ij` will not suffer from rounding errors.

Answer (score 2):

try [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
long number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.printf(Locale.GERMAN, "%,.2f", new Double(number/100d) );
```

output

```
21.474.836,47
```

Comment: AFAIK, there's no need for the `new Double(...)`: simply do `number/100d`

Comment: `printf()` needs Objects - and I don't like auto-boxing

Answer (score 0):

Use decimals.

```
final BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(32301672060L), 2);
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(dec));
```

or instead of the pattern, better to use locale's formats, e.g.

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(dec));
```

or

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(dec));
```